# powershell вывести дополнительное поле

Tags: powershell, acl

Есть задача получить список прав доступа к папкам
пробую так:

```
Get-ChildItem $Root | 
    Get-ACL  | select -expand access | select * | 
        where {$_.AccessControlType -Ne 'Deny'} |  
        where {$_.IdentityReference -Ne 'СОЗДАТЕЛЬ-ВЛАДЕЛЕЦ'} |
        where {$_.IdentityReference -Ne 'NT AUTHORITY\СИСТЕМА'} |
        where {$_.IdentityReference -Ne 'BUILTIN\Администраторы'} | Format-Table –AutoSize
```

он выводит столбики

select  IdentityReference, AccessControlType, FileSystemRights, IsInherited

вопрос: как можно вывести в таблицу дополнительно данные о папке.
чтоб был список вида: папка | группа пользователей | и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно select'ом выбрать все столбцы с раскрытием прав, а затем указать нужные в Format-Table:

```
Get-ChildItem $Root | 
    Get-ACL  | select * -expand access | 
        where {$_.AccessControlType -Ne 'Deny'} |  
        where {$_.IdentityReference -Ne 'СОЗДАТЕЛЬ-ВЛАДЕЛЕЦ'} |
        where {$_.IdentityReference -Ne 'NT AUTHORITY\СИСТЕМА'} |
        where {$_.IdentityReference -Ne 'BUILTIN\Администраторы'} |
    Format-Table @{Label="Path"; Expression={Convert-Path $_.Path}}, Group, Owner,
        IdentityReference, AccessControlType, FileSystemRights, IsInherited –AutoSize
```